# Debug image/production image in the docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

[Docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/dev-best-practices/) suggest an approach:

> To keep your production image lean but allow for debugging, consider using the production image as the base image for the debug image. Additional testing or debugging tooling can be added on top of the production image.

But which way is the best to achieve that? In my case I have a statically linked binary, which requires only a basic libs, which are provided by the small `rhel-minimal` image.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel-minimal:latest
COPY app /app/
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

I could build an another image based on the one created by my Dockerfile, but it seems inappropriate, because I have to do this for every image, which I create. All I want is a sort of mechanism, which allows me to change from the `rhel-minimal` base image to some `rhel-minimal-with-debug-utils`, when I want to start a debugging session. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q.** All I want is a sort of mechanism, which allows me to change from
> the rhel-minimal base image to some rhel-minimal-with-debug-utils,
> when I want to start a debugging session. Is that possible?

**Solution 1:**

You can keep a copy of your base image in your docker repository as well.
For example,

- Production base image: `localregistry/rhel-minimal:latest`
- Debugging base image:  `localregistry/rhel-minimal:debug`

---

**Solution 2:**

You can also leverage docker [multi-staging](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to build multiple images using a single Dockerfile for testing, debugging, and production.